# Logic App to delete ARM demployment history

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I am really new to Logic Apps and I have created my first LA to delete ARM Deployment History to help alleviate this deployment error with max quota for deployments:

> Creating the deployment [DEPLOYMENT_NAME] would exceed the quota of
>   ‘800’. The current deployment count is ‘800’, please delete some
>   deployments before creating a new one.

The LA I have created lists all deployments and after that deletes them via a For Each loop action. But this deletes ALL my deployment history. I want to keep the latest 100 deployments,

How can I skip the first 100 deployments in my Logic App? I am not sure how to use the Filter or Top parameters.

In PowerShell I can accomplish this easily with this line:

```
Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName myRG | Select -Skip 100 | Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment
```

How can I do this in my Logic App?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input of your for each could use the [`skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#skip) function for this. The input expression would be something like this

```
skip(body('List_template_deployments'), 100)
```

[image: logic-app-designer-screenshot]